# Wordpress plugin - how to disable plugin automatic updates

Tags: wordpress

I am using the wordpress plugin "WooCommerce Product Sort and Display LITE", where I have made few modifications to suit my site, but unfortunately my site crashes every night due to plugin automatic update to new version and I have to restore it from backup. I am trying to figure out how to disable the plugin automatic updates, but no luck so far.

I tried to add the following filter into theme `function.php`:
`add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_false' );` - no help

tried to increase version number - no help

Also tried to find from source code where to disable updates, but I do not have deep knowledges in php, so I hope that someone here could help me out with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this code to disable auto-updates of specific plugin:

```
function disable_plugin_updates( $value ) {
   unset( $value->response['plugin-folder-name/plugin-index.php'] );
   return $value;
}
add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'disable_plugin_updates' );
```

Comment: Where is this filter defined?  I searched the core and can't find any reference to it.

Comment: @AndrewSchultz See this link: http://hookr.io/filters/site_transient_update_plugins/

Comment: to where I have to put this code, into theme function.php?

Comment: @ziil Usually at the end of the function.php file

Comment: You can add this code to the main file of the plugin itself and base the argument to add_filter on  `__FILE__`.  This way if moves with the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Typically to turn off auto-updates in wordpress you add this line to your `wp-config.php:`

```
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );
```